# Solid revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I compute the solid revolution about y-axis of the function(volume) $f(x)= x^2$ if $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $f(x) = 1$  if $1 \leq x \leq 1.25$[image]

Someone can help to understand this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this with washers of shells?

Suppose you want to do washers.

Then we slice this object in a series of parallel horizontal slices.  If we are making horizontal slices we will be integrating with respect to $y.$

Each of the cross sections is a washer (a disk, with a concentric disk removed).  The area of each washer = $\pi (R^2 - r^2)$, where $R$ is outer radius, and $r$ is the inner radius.

The thickness of each washer is $dy.$

$R = 1.25\\
r = \sqrt y$

$V = \pi\int (1.25^2 - y) dy$
What are the limits for y?  The smallest value of y is 0, the largest is 1

$V = \pi\int_0^1 (1.25^2 - y) dy$

I am partial to shells myself, but that means you will need to calculate 2 integrals, and is probably a little bit harder for this problem.

If you do shells, then the volume of each shell is the surface area of a cylinder * thickness of the wall.

$SA = 2\pi r h\\
r = x\\
h = \begin{cases} x^2& x\le 1\\ 1& x>1\end{cases}$

the thickness is $dx$

$V = 2\pi (\int_0^1 x^3 dx + \int_1^{1.25}  x\, dx)$

And hopefully those two integrals equal one another.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to subtract a negative volume

$$ \int x^2 dy  = \int_0^1 y\, dy $$

from surrounding  cylinder of radius 1.25 and height 1.

Answer (score 1):

You want the volume ? Notice that in $(O,x,t,y)$, your function is given by
$$y=f(x,t)=\begin{cases}
x^2+t^2&x^2+t^2\leq 1\\
1&1\leq x^2+t^2\leq (1.25)^2
\end{cases}.$$

I let you conclude.

Comment: Yes I want to find the volume

Comment: @Knight: Then, you have all elements to compute the volume !

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use Pappus's $(2^{nd})$ Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area A and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2πR$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2πRA$. When dealing with a composite area, as here, the centroid is the area-weighted average of the component parts. Thus, if we let subscripts 1 and 2 represent the parabola and rectangle, respectively, then

$$R=\frac{A_1R_1+A_2R_2}{A_1+A_2}\\
V=2\pi(A_1R_1+A_2R_2)
$$

Of course, these centroids, $R_{1,2}$ are relative to the (vertical) $z$-axis. That is, the centroid is given by

$$R=\frac{\int xf(x)dx}{\int f(x)dx}=\frac{\int xf(x)dx}{A}$$

Without any further ado, it's easy to verify that

$$
A_1=-\frac{1}{3},\quad R_1A_1=-\frac{1}{4},\quad \text{i.e., a negative area}\\
A_2=\frac{5}{4},\quad R_2A_2=\frac{25}{32}
$$

Finally, we arrive at the volume

$$V=2\pi(A_1R_1+A_2R_2)=2\pi\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{25}{32}\right)\approx 3.3379$$

This result has been verified by numerical integration.